# Listfield having headers/section

Tags: blackberry, header, listfield

i am new to blackberry and do not know much about it. I am learning and implementing list having too many sections/headers.For that i have implemented so far:
[image]

here is my code:

```
public  class MyScreen extends MainScreen
    {
        /**
         * Creates a new MyScreen object
         */
        public MyScreen()
        {        
            super(Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL);
            setTitle("Simple List Demo");
    
            add(new LabelField("A"));
            add(new SeparatorField());
            
            Manager mainManager = getMainManager();
            
            SimpleList listField = new SimpleList(mainManager);
            
            listField.add("Item 1");
            listField.add("Item 2");
            listField.add("Item 3");
            
            add(new SeparatorField());
            add(new LabelField("B"));
            add(new SeparatorField());
            
            SimpleList list=new SimpleList(mainManager);
    
            list.add("Item 4");
            list.add("Item 5");
            list.add("Item 6");
            
            add(new SeparatorField());
            
        }
    }
```

I want to implement as:
[image]

Can anybody share the idea how to implement this sort of listfield.I have taken two listfields and added separatorField,labelfield to distinguish but this is not the way as this would be too tedious to implement and maintain too many lists.Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Akash

Answer (score 0):

It is not one `ListField` instance on the screen. There are several `ListField` instances separated by `LabelField` instances.

Just add combinations of `LabelField` and `ListField` instances to the one screen.

Comment: Thanks @Rafael.But wont it be too tedious to maintain and implement too many listfields as i mentioned in my question??

Comment: Nope, it won't be tedious if you implement a good design approach. For instance combine functionality to control one pair of labelfield and listfield in one class, group similar functionality and so on.

Comment: can u help me with the code @Rafael..it would be a great help to me if you do so.

Comment: The approach is the same for all `label+list` pairs. Declare a class that holds LabelField and ListField instance, and implements ListFieldCallbackListener to serve its own ListField instance. Constructor of this class must receive reference to parent screen instance. And in constructor of this class you add label and list to the parent screen. That's it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rafael for your response but can you please help me with the code only for A & B,rest i will manage.it would be a great help to me if you do so.